# Counting total number of builds in a Teamcity project

Tags: teamcity

How can I get total number of builds that have run in a particular teamcity project? 
I understand there is autoincrementor plugin but to use this I will need to configure all the old projects.

I am looking of a REST API in teamcity, if that can give me total number of builds for even a build configuration then I can get project total by adding up all the numbers for build configurations under a project.

Thanks
Pratibha

Answer (score 1):

```
http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/
```

This will return xml like:

```
<builds count="100" .....>
 <build id="1" .....
 .....
 ....
</builds>
```

count is what you are looking for.
If you are looking for builds in a project, you can use

```
http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/projects/<ProjectLocator>/buildTypes
```

This will give you something like:

```
<buildTypes>
  <buildType id="1" ... />
  <buildType id="2" ... />
</buildTypes>
```

There is no count attribute here, you'll need to count the list.

Comment: Thanks this REST Api gives build count for all the projects on the server. Is there an api that can give me build count only for a specific project? I can not use build number to count that because I have some custom values in build numbers.

Comment: Updated the answer, added REST to get list of builds in a project.